# Godot play video after file load

Tags: godot, functional

I used WebM video in my game but it's lagging. The audio is few secs delayed then video. Is there any way to load the video first then play so that the lagging doesn't occurs

Comment: How have you set up your video to play so far?

Comment: Yes i have set it

Comment: I did not ask "have you set it up?", I asked "*HOW* have you set it up?" — **please edit your question to walk us through the steps you took**, and any relevant code or UI configuration.

Comment: by controller node

Comment: There are many known issues with WebM video playback (https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+webm+label%3Abug), I'd try using the Ogg Theora format instead.